# finding strings in csv and return column number using c#

Tags: c#, string, csv

I have tried to find out how to search for a specific string found in a cell in a csv and return the column number. I have found out how to return the row number but I also need the column. I was thinking of a way to maybe count the number of CSV-separators before the string I'm looking for occurs. Do you have an idea of how I can do this? This is how I did to determain the row number.

```
foreach (var match in File.ReadLines(filePath)
                      .Select((text, index) => new { text, lineNumber = index + 1 })
                      .Where(x => x.text.Contains("CH1_Value")))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", match.lineNumber, match.text);
}
```

Comment: so, did you try Kyle's or mine suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach using Linq and anonymous types:

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(filePath).ToList();
string textToSearch = "CH1_Value";
int lineIndex = lines.Select((l, ix) => new { line = l, index = ix })
    .FirstOrDefault(l => l.line.Contains(textToSearch)).index;
int columnIndex = lines[lineIndex].Split(',').Select((c, ix) => new { col = c, index = ix })
    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.col.Contains(textToSearch)).index;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your lines into columns, then find the matching column text.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(filePath);

var lineIdx = 0;
var colIdx = 0;

foreach(var line in lines) {
    lineIdx++;
    foreach(var column in line.Split(',')) { // split cols here
        colIdx++;
        if(column.Contains("target_text")) {
            // found in {lineIdx} and {colIdx}
        }
    }
    colIdx = 0; // reset col index
}
```